# Is propane-1,2,3-tricarbaldehyde the correct IUPAC name of CHO-CH2-CH(CHO)-CH2-CHO?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds

We were asked this question in class:

> What is the IUPAC name of the compound $\ce{CHO-CH2-CH(CHO)-CH2-CHO}?$

I don't know for sure, but I think the answer should either be 3-formylpentan-1,5-dial or 2-(formylmethyl)-butane-1,4-dial. However, I am told that the correct answer is propane-1,2,3-tricarbaldehyde.

How can that be? I searched on the internet and found that we use 'carbaldehyde' as the suffix *only* when the $\ce{-CHO}$ group is attached to a *ring*. But *here* the given compound is an open chain compound, so I don't see why we're using 'carbaldehyde' as the suffix.

My course textbook mentions that this compound is named so "to give identical treatment to all aldehydic groups". But I haven't learnt that such a rule exists in IUPAC nomenclature.

**What is the correct name of this compound and why?**

Comment: Related: [When is the carbaldehyde suffix correct?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19868/7951)

Comment: Related: [1,1-diformyl propanal](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/58339/103369)

Answer (score 4):

From the Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013, let's cite one of the rules for usage of the -carbaldehyde suffix, the relevant one:

> **P-66.6.1.1.2** The suffix ‘carbaldehyde’ is used when more than two $\ce{-CHO}$ groups are attached to an alkane.
>
> Example:
>
> $\ce{OHC-\overset{1}{C}H2-\overset{2}{C}H(CHO)-\overset{3}{C}H2-\overset{4}{C}H2-CHO}$
>   butane-1,2,4-tricarbaldehyde (PIN)

Thus the correct name is **propane-1,2,3-tricarbaldehyde**.