# Difference between oxo and formyl

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the difference between oxo and formyl? both represent aldehyde when used as a substituent(correct me if I am wrong). But when should I use formyl and when oxo?

[This](https://the-educational-blog.quora.com/IUPAC-nomenclature-for-organic-compounds-Part-VI-Aldehydes-and-ketones) answers my problem and also says that oxo is also used for aldehyde.

> ALDEHYDES:
>
> If they get priority in the name they get the suffix ‘al’ or ‘carbaldehyde’
> As substituent prefixes ‘oxo’ and ‘formyl’ are used. The prefix ‘formyl’ is used in preferred IUPAC names, except for a -CHO group at the end of an acyclic chain.

However he did not give any sources.

Comment: No, oxo means ketone.

Comment: @IvanNeretin its almost certainly right. Oxo is also used for aldehyde.https://the-educational-blog.quora.com/IUPAC-nomenclature-for-organic-compounds-Part-VI-Aldehydes-and-ketones.

Comment: Partly related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/58339/7951 and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19868/7951

Comment: Oxo is the "O" of a ketone or aldehyde functional group as in 4-oxocyclohexane-1-carboxylic acid or 6-oxohexanoic acid.

Answer (score 7):

> Oxo is the substituent name for the $\ce{=O}$ group of an aldehyde or a ketone if that group is found on the longest continuous carbon chain that contains a higher priority group.

e.g., $\ce{OHC-CH2-CH2-CH2-CH2-CO2H =}$ 6-oxohexanoic acid

If the aldehyde carbon is not part of the longest continuous chain, then it becomes a formyl substituent.

e.g., $\ce{CH3-CH2-CH(-CHO)-CH2-CH2-CO2H =}$ 4-formylhexanoic acid

Comment: Welcome to our site! Could you perhaps add a few referenced (preferably from the IUPAC Blue Book), to back your answer up? Nomenclature systems are defined as standards, hence the requirement of references.

Answer (score 4):

"Oxo" refers to a substitution of a *single oxygen atom on a carbon atom by a double bond*.  "Formyl" refers to the substitution of a *three atom HCO* group onto a different carbon or other atom.

I'll leave it to others to explain the differences in IUPAC nomenclature.

So for example 3-oxopentanal has five carbons just like pentanal, but it has one extra oxygen atom, double bonded to carbon #3.  (This means it has two less hydrogens, a fact that the nomenclature elides.) This is a case where "oxo" refers to a ketone, not an aldehyde.

"Formyl" is sometimes used as a substituent, but not always.  "Formyl benzene" is a incorrect name for benzaldehyde, but 4-formylbenzoic acid does exist and is used in practice as the name of chemical.